# Set div position while page scrolls

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I know similar questions have been asked but I've not seen this one. !

I have 3 divs on my page.

WRAP is the main page wrapper and provides a border around the inner divs.

OUTER is the outer div

RIGHT is the div I want to move as the page scrolls.

[image]

You can see on this image where RIGHT sits, as the page scrolls down I want right to move with it.

I've tried setting the CSS position to fixed, but if the page is resized this messes up the layout. The css I currently have is :

```
#wrap 
{ 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
    border:2px solid #800000; 
}

#outer 
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 1250px;
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid #000008;
}

#right 
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #008000;
}
```

I've created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2szxxvw/1/)** with how this currently looks.

How do I get right to move correctly with the page ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this? https://jsfiddle.net/r2szxxvw/2/

Comment: @NKL yes but.. If you resize the page the right div is in a different position. If you run the fiddle full screen the right div is now outside of the Outer div, when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RouthMedia's answer works, but if you have different constraints, like "it shouldn't be on top of the content if the window is smaller than the layout"

To solve that, you can have a `window.onresize` function that changes the div's right position depending on the constraints you want to have.

```
window.onresize = function(event) 
{
    // is the window smaller than something it shouldn't? calculate the new position
    ("#right").css("right", newpos);
};
```

**Edit:** saw you don't want it out of the outer div.

One way to do it: When the page loads, set the "right" property to something that puts it inside the outer div. If the screen resizes, update it.

Another way to do it: use `position: absolute`, and update the "top" property with the document.scrollTop value when the `onscroll` event fires.

Comment: Thx - Do you have any example for scrollTop and onscroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:fixed; right:0px;` to your `#right` div.

Comment: I did and that pushes the right div outside of the outer div.

Comment: I have changed the wording slightly